# Why do they use "at all" in positive sentences?

Tags: word-usage

In the dictionary: [at all](https://www.ldoceonline.com/dictionary/at-all)

> used in **negative statements** and **questions** to emphasize what you are
>   saying
>
> They’ve done nothing at all to try and put the problem right.
>
> He’s not looking at all well.
>
> ‘Do you mind if I stay a little longer?’ ‘No, not at all.’
>
> Has the situation improved at all?

But people do say "**But many people think it is sad that she wanted to change her appearance at all.**" which is **a positive sentence**

Why do they use "**at all**" in positive sentences?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**at all** can be used with both negative and positive.

Say nothing at all.  Keep quiet.

Say anything at all.  Say whatever you like.

Comment: Yes, those examples work!  Eureka!  I don't think that "at all" in the second one means the same thing as her "at all" in the negative.  That's the reason it was so confusing to me.

Comment: Compare **whatsoever**.